# cannot instal discord module properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

while installing the module, i get this error

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Trial>pip install discordpy
Collecting discordpy
  Using cached discordpy-0.1.1.tar.gz (1.3 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for discordpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: discordpy
    Running setup.py install for discordpy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ogovpl6m\\discordpy_7005c477f7d447de9f394c1c31fd29bc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ogovpl6m\\discordpy_7005c477f7d447de9f394c1c31fd29bc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t2eexxn7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\discordpy'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ogovpl6m\discordpy_7005c477f7d447de9f394c1c31fd29bc\
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ogovpl6m\discordpy_7005c477f7d447de9f394c1c31fd29bc\setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ogovpl6m\discordpy_7005c477f7d447de9f394c1c31fd29bc\setup.py", line 20, in run
        raise Exception("You probably meant to install and run discord-py")
    Exception: You probably meant to install and run discord-py
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ogovpl6m\\discordpy_7005c477f7d447de9f394c1c31fd29bc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ogovpl6m\\discordpy_7005c477f7d447de9f394c1c31fd29bc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t2eexxn7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\discordpy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

and to double check when i try running with this code-

```
from discord.ext import commands
code=commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')
@client.event
async def when_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")
@client.command()
async def hello(abcd):
    await abcd.send("Hi")
client.run('the bot token, cant share')
```

the error was shown to me was this

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Trial\bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    @client.event
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

pls help out , so i need to spam so that my question get subbmitted and i dont get a error regarding that your post is mostly code , please add some more details?

Comment: What python version are you using? Also to fix the second error (`client is not defined`) simply rename the `code` variable to `client`

Comment: i was using it in pycharm which is 2020.1.1 x64 version. and i got python IDLE too of version 3.8(32bit).

Comment: `pip install discord.py` should get you an up-to-date version of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. its `discord.py` so `pip install -U discord.py`
2. You use whatever you define `Client` or `Bot` to, so it will be `@code.event`, `@code.command()` and so

Comment: ok thanks a lot, it worked, everything was fine just the variable name i wrote wrong while using it later in the command, any other place can I contact u ?